# Pass IDs to pre_get_posts query in function

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, function

I am trying to pass the post ids to the function's query->set and function will return the posts.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'query_booked_posts' );

function query_booked_posts( $query ) {
    if ( $condition ) { //the condition

    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
    $results = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT booked_id FROM $wpdb->userbooking WHERE userid = %d",$current_user_id));

    foreach($results as $result){
    $results_separated = $result.',';
    }
    $query->set ('post__in', array($results_separated)); // pass results (post ids) to post__in

    return $query;
    }

}
```

After this, the function returns nothing.

If I do `$query->set ('post__in', array(45,121));`,  the query will return the posts of id 45 and id 121, so the query works fine.

But I want to make `$results_separated` pass the post ids like 45,121,132 to the query, and then `$query->set ('post__in', array($results_separated));` will work correctly.
How can I make this happen?

[`pre_get_posts` reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have actually a PHP problem. When you do `array($results_separated)` you're basically creating an array from a string that looks like this: `"12,114,56,"`. By doing that, PHP is creating an array like this:

```
array(
    0 => "12,114,56,"
)
```

And obviously WordPress cannot find any posts with such ID! What you want is actually an array like this:

```
array(
    0 => "12",
    1 => "114",
    2 => "56"
)
```

And actually that's what `get_col()` returns, so you just need to pass `$results` to `set()` function:

```
$query->set ( 'post__in', $results );
```

---

***EDIT***: Actually I realised that your problem is when you call `$wpdb->get_col(...)`, because it's interfering with the `$query` you will execute later on... Those variables are using some other global variables that probably get overriden, and that's why you're not getting any results...

Comment: Thank you MikO, I just tried your solution but still returns nothing :(

Comment: @Jason, try doing a `var_dump($results)` just before your `foreach`, to make sure you're actually getting some results from your query...

Comment: After var_dump($results) I get this: array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "121" [1]=> string(2) "89" [2]=> string(2) "69" }

Comment: Hi MikO, I found a very strange thing. I change the function to:if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
$results_separated = '46,121';
$query->set ('post__in', array($results_separated));
return $query;
 the function will still return nothing.

Comment: And if I use query like this it works. $query->set ('post__in', array(46,121));  this is very strange to me.

Comment: @Jason, what you were trying in your previous comment (not the last one) is obviously not working, because you're making the same mistake than in your question (you cannot create an `array('46,21')`! Try using directly `$results` into `$query->set()` as I edited in my answer...

Comment: Yes, I just tried the $query->set ( 'post__in', $results ); without foreach. and still with no luck, returns nothing. And I believe have tried that before I ask the question.

Comment: @Jason, when you try with `$query->set ('post__in', array(46,121));` and it works fine, are you calling `$wpdb->get_col(...)` anyway? Because I think the problem is the use of `$wpdb` is making the actual `$query` not working... Probably it overrides some variable or something like that...

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time MikO. I think you are right MikO. How to resolve this to make the function work correctly? The problem really bothers me because I don't know where is the issue, after all this I think it should work but it didn't.

Comment: @Jason, I edited my answer including this conclusions. I suggest you to mark this answer as accepted, think about what you're trying to achieve and post a new question explaining your situation and asking how to do it in a different way. I'm sure there's a better way to do whatever you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

Except the extra array() over $results_separated, in my case I had to apply

```
if (!$query->is_main_query()) {
    return $query;
}
```

at the top of my function (found it in, otherwise, queries inside would be executed for several times and not properly.
Comments in the answer helped me to figure this out.