# pass post ids to pre_get_posts query post__in function

Tags: php, function, wordpress

I want to let the function return the posts by the query->set with post ids post__in, But the function returns nothing.
Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'query_booked_posts' );

function query_booked_posts( $query ) {
global $post,$wpdb;

$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ( is_page(21) ) { //the condition, work fine

if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
$results = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT booked_id FROM $wpdb->userbooking WHERE userid = %d",$current_user_id));

$query->set ('post__in', array($results)); // pass results (post ids) to post__in

return $query;
}

}
```

Thanks

Jason

Comment: Where do you define `$condition` and `$current_user_id` ?

Comment: sorry about that, added

Comment: ok, I updated the answer. ps: please format your code ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this instead:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'query_booked_posts' );

function query_booked_posts( $query )
{
    if ( is_page( 21 ) && is_user_logged_in() &&  $query->is_main_query() )
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $results = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( 
                   "SELECT booked_id FROM $wpdb->userbooking 
                    WHERE userid = %d",
                    get_current_user_id() ) );

        $query->set ( 'post__in', $results ); 
    }
    return $query;
}
```

where I replaced:

- your undefined `$condition` with `is_user_logged_in()`.
- the undefined `$get_current_user_id` with `get_current_user_id()`.
- the extra array around `$results`, since the `get_col` method returns an array.
- the `is_home()` check since you also use `is_page(21)`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks birgire. But it's not working. here is my same question asked before, after all that we still can't find the solution it's very strange. I hope you can help us with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847087/ppass-ids-to-pre-get-posts-query-in-function

Comment: ok will check it out tomorrow, very late here ;-) ps: I also added `global $wpdb`.

Comment: Thank you birgire. The main problem is the $results(post ids) seems can't pass to post__in. Don't know where is the issue :(

Comment: Until tomorrow, you can try to add the missing `global $wpdb`, your code won't work without it - and use `WP_DEBUG`  to help you with debugging. cheers

Comment: Thanks birgire, the $wpdb added. Still returns nothing.

Comment: Hi, some questions here: When you use `is_page(21)`, you want to match the post type `page` with `ID` as `21`. Further you want to  target the main query of the the frontpage/homepage. You see the problem here, right? Also what kind of post type to you want to add via `post__in` ? Where do you define `$wpdb->userbooking`, usually custom table names are not automatically available this way. Try to echo the SQL query above, to check it. Try to describe it in more detail what you want, and we could take it from there. What about secondary loop in a custom page template on your homepage?

Answer (score 0):

You might also need

```
if (!$query->is_main_query()) {
    return $query;
}
```

if you'll find some strange results. I have found this by the link to similar question in the answer's comments.