# WordPress Display Sidebar on Specific Posts

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to display a custom sidebar if the page is one of 3 pages (all a custom post type), and I can't seem to figure out how to make this possible.  I have properly registered "Custom Sidebar" in functions.php.  How can I call this sidebar on multiple pages, and then show the regular sidebar on others?

```
enter code here



   <?php
    if(is_singular('5894'))  {
        get_sidebar('Custom Sidebar');     }
    else{
        get_sidebar(); //get sidebar.php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) you should be able to use something like

```
is_singular( 'book' );
```

where `book` is the name of your Custom Post Type.

---

If this won't work as expected try out to place another [Conditional Tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) in your template file. Perhaps also [`is_page_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) is what you are looking for.
If you want to get more information about your template file, place some kind of code like the following in it:

```
global $page;
var_dump( $page );
```

---

**EDIT:**

Since the OP's comment I think he's looking the [`pre_get_posts`](http://devotepress.com/wordpress-coding/when-to-use-pre_get_posts-in-wordpress/#.Vc9zI5dCjOQ)-[filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847087/ppass-ids-to-pre-get-posts-query-in-function) .

Your code could look something like the following:

```
function exclude_ids_from_search_query( $query ) {
    global $page; //perhaps you have to check for the pagename in if-statement

    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) : //e.g. check for pagename, post_type, etc...
        $ids = array( 10, 12, 66, 70 ); //Post ID's included in search
        $query->set( 'post__in', $ids );
    endif;

    return $query;
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_ids_from_search_query' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I think I may have not made the question clear.   I would like to only target **certain** posts within a custom post type.  It would be great to be able to just enter the post IDs within the code and target that way.  Is this possible?